# Why doesn't my View respond to a gesture using a gestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

Having just spent a day beating my head against the keyboard, I thought I'd share my diagnosis and solution.

Situation: You add a custom View of custom class `CardView` to an enclosing view `myCards` in your app and want each card to respond to a tap gesture (for example to indicate you want to discard the card). Typical code you start with:

In your ViewController:

```
class MyVC : UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
...
    func discardedCard(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let cv : CardView = sender.view! as! CardView
         ...
    }
```

In your myCards construction:

```
cv  = CardView(card: card)
myCards.addSubview(cv)
cv.userInteractionEnabled = true
...
let cvTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("discardedCard:"))
cvTap.delegate = self
cv.addGestureRecognizer(cvTap)
```

I found the arguments here very confusing and the documentation not at all helpful. It isn't clear that the `target: argument` refers to the class that implements `discardedCard(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)` . If you're constructing the recognizer and cards in your `ViewController` that's going to be `self`. If you want to move the `discardedCard` into your custom View class (for example), then replace `self` with `CardView` in my example, including on the delegate line.

Testing the above code, I found that the discardedCard function was never called. What was going on?

Comment: By the way, you don't need to specify the number of taps or touches; defaults are 1 and 1: According to the docs, the default is 1 touch (fingers) and 1 tap: see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITapGestureRecognizer/numberOfTouchesRequired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a day later, here's what I had to fix. I hope this checklist is useful to somebody else. I'm new to iOS (coming from Android), so it may be obvious to you veterans:

1. Make sure the touched view (`cv` in the example) has `userInteractionEnabled=true` . Note that if you use your own constructor it will be set **false** by default
2. Make sure **all enclosing views** also have `userInteractionEnabled=true`
3. Others have posted that the order of the `delegate` statement and `addGestureRecognizer` statement made a difference; I didn't find that using Xcode 7.2 and iOS 9.2
4. Most important: Make sure your touched view is **fully within the bounds of the enclosing views**. In my example, I was building a `myCards` container that didn't have the width set correctly and was cutting off the right-most cards (and since clipping is disabled by default, this wasn't visually obvious until I looked in the debugger at the View hierarchy)